# Posicionar botão em baixo da table não está funcionando

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-6

Com esse HTML não consigo posicionar os botões em baixo da tabela. Já tentei várias formas, a atual foi outra tentativa.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form style="width:400px; margin: 0 auto;">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Código</th>
                            <th>Nome</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let operator of dataSource">
                            <td>{{ operator.operatorId }}</td>
                            <td>{{ operator.name }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>                
            </form>          
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Atualizar</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Deletar</button>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Veja como aparece os botões **Atualizar e Deletar**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal seria "encapsular" os BTNs dentro de uma `.row` como diz a documentação. Além disso, não vejo porque vc colocar a sua `<table>` dentro de um `<form>`

Testa com esse código para ver se resolve. Repare que troquei a tag `form` por uma `div` e separei os btns em outra `row`

OBS: Esse código funciona tando no BS3 quanto no 4

Dica: Confira inspecionando os elementos ou no seu CSS se a primeira .row com a tabela não está com `position:absolute` setado.

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div style="width:400px; margin: 0 auto;">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Código</th>
                            <th>Nome</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let operator of dataSource">
                            <td>{{ operator.operatorId }}</td>
                            <td>{{ operator.name }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>                
            </div>          
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Deletar</button>  
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Atualizar</button>
      </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Está dentro porque fui fazendo testes e essa foi a última posição. Mas não existe form nessa table, foi apenas para testar

Comment: @pnet já deu um inspect na table para verificar os estilos? Outra coisa, vc "printa" essa tabela na página depois que ela é renderizada? Tente pegar o código do jeito que aparece dando um Ctrl+U na página no Browser, e não o código que vc tem no arquivo.html etc entende. Ai coloca o código na pergunta

Comment: Cara, valeu. Era o css da página: `table {
    width: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 15%;
  }

    mat-row:nth-child(even){
    background-color:red;
  }
  
    mat-row:nth-child(odd){
    background-color:yellow;
  }`

Comment: @pnet sabia que poderia ser isso rss. Tanto que tinha deixado a "Dica:" ai na resposta. Mas que bom que resolveu, acompanhei seu drama ai esses dias com essas perguntas da table e sempre desconfiei que era isso, por isso te mandei inspecionar o elemento!